# Why is the program printing float different in debug and release?

Tags: c++, tcp

I have a strange problem, that I can't fix. I am sending 3 float values over TCP from a microcontroller. On my PC I simply want to print those values. When I run the code in release mode, it only prints the number in front of the decimal point. But when I debug the program, everything works just fine.

This is the code:

```
char laserL_Buffer[32];
char laserR_Buffer[32];
char laserM_Buffer[32];

TCPConnector* connector = new TCPConnector();
TCPStream* stream = connector->connect("10.42.0.2",3333);

//Send l for laserData
char cT = 'l';
stream->send(&cT,1);

//Receive the Data for Left Right and Middle Range from laserScanner
stream->receive(laserL_Buffer,32);
stream->receive(laserR_Buffer,32);
stream->receive(laserM_Buffer,32);

delete stream;

float l = strtof(laserL_Buffer,nullptr);
float m = strtof(laserM_Buffer,nullptr);
float r = strtof(laserR_Buffer,nullptr);

std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << l << std::endl;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << m << std::endl;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << r << std::endl;
```

Okay thanks for all the answers, I just figured out the problem. I changed the strtof to boost::lexical_cast. Then it worked fine.

Comment: Not sure if related, but: Are you sure you want to `delete stream`, or should it be `delete connector`?

Comment: offtopic: `//Send p for position  char cT = 'l';` that is the main reason I dislike comments.

Comment: Is the content of `laserX_Buffer` the same in release and debug?

Comment: Have you complied in maximal warning mode, and confirmed that any warnings issued are not a problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusing comment, its just a little test i wanted to write fast.
How can I check the content while the program is running?
Yes I compiled in maximal warning mode and confirmed that any warnings issued are not a problem

Comment: I also tried to add     delete connector but it didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @OliverS. Did you remove the `delete stream;` then? Could be that this calls undefined behavior.

Comment: @user0042. Yes I did.

Comment: How do you check that something have been received and the buffers are null-terminated?

Comment: @OliverS. I'd bet on undefined behavior though.

Comment: @VTT. I don't. I know it would be good practice to do so, but I just wanted a small and fast code block, that executes depending on a button to see if the correct values are beeing send.

Answer (score 1):

Release mode may have a different FP strategy set. There are different floating point arithmetic modes depending on the level of optimization you'd like. MSVC, for example, has strict, fast, and precise modes.

Comment: Okay, where can I change the mode, or check which mode I have selected? 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Take a look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx?ppud=4

Comment: I inserted 

    #pragma float_control(precise, on, push)  
// Code that uses /fp:precise mode  
#pragma float_control(pop)

But it didnt change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I guess that you send exactly 32 characters for each float and your buffers have lenght 32, so they are not zero-ended. Make them 33 bytes long and set last one to zero, so strtof will know when to end parsing and see if it works. I wish I could tell you why exactly it works different in debug than in release, but basicly in debug you have some handicap and compiler might have placed your local variables into zeroed memory space. In release they are most likely aligned for optimization.

```
char laserL_Buffer[33];
char laserR_Buffer[33];
char laserM_Buffer[33];

TCPConnector* connector = new TCPConnector();
TCPStream* stream = connector->connect("10.42.0.2",3333);

//Send l for laserData
char cT = 'l';
stream->send(&cT,1);

//Receive the Data for Left Right and Middle Range from laserScanner
stream->receive(laserL_Buffer,32);
stream->receive(laserR_Buffer,32);
stream->receive(laserM_Buffer,32);

laserL_Buffer[32] = laserR_Buffer[32] = laserM_Buffer[32] = 0;
delete stream;

float l = strtof(laserL_Buffer,nullptr);
float m = strtof(laserM_Buffer,nullptr);
float r = strtof(laserR_Buffer,nullptr);

std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << l << std::endl;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << m << std::endl;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(8) << r << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that out, but it didn't solve my problem.
I think I made a little mistake in my question. The problem is not between the debug and release. I get the correct value when i set a breakpoint and if I run the program normally the behaviour is as described above.

Comment: Ok, so what if you narrow down your code to just printing? Try to pin down minimal example. Is method of getting float values relevant if your problem goes down to showing them? Try giving same values from rand() (so it does not get inlined by compiler) and see if it repeats

Comment: Okay I tried to send a fixed float value over tcp, but that didn't work either. I also tried to print some random floats, that works fine.

Comment: @OliverS. Have you tried to print buffers that you receive? Maybe there is some coding error? Or are you sure that both sides use dot '.'?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure that both use dot. I just figured out, that I even dont have to use a breakpoint. When I press the normal play button in Qt Creator it doesn't work, but when I use the debug button, even without breakpoints, it works. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: @OliverS. So, you might have some time races here. When you debug program works slower and device is fast enough to answer, but normally it does not. Is `stream->receive` blocking and waiting for input? That's why I'd try printing out buffers that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to the following, then it worked.

```
char laserL_Buffer[8];
char laserR_Buffer[8];
char laserM_Buffer[8];
LaserData l_data;

TCPConnector* connector = new TCPConnector();
TCPStream* stream = connector->connect("10.42.0.2",3333);

//Send p for position
char cT = 'l';
stream->send(&cT,1);

//Receive the Data for Left Right and Middle Range from laserScanner
stream->receive(laserL_Buffer,8);
stream->receive(laserR_Buffer,8);
stream->receive(laserM_Buffer,8);

delete stream;
delete connector;

l_data.laserLeftRange = boost::lexical_cast<float>(laserL_Buffer);
l_data.laserRightRange = boost::lexical_cast<float>(laserR_Buffer);
l_data.laserMidRange = boost::lexical_cast<float>(laserM_Buffer);
```

Comment: Nice that you got it working, but it rises another question: why it works now? ;) And why it didn't ealier. Also, I still believe that you should zero-terminate your char buffers.

Comment: Yes true, I should do that. I don't know why it works. I think something about the memory went wrong. Or something caused undefined behaviour.